# UIScrollview setContentsize in self.view.bounds.size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have code like this in which i dont't want to use this number in place of i want to take size from current view's height,width

```
  [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(786, 1400)];
```

I did like this,

```
  [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 2.2)];
```

but i having problem in iphone4s and ipad..
Is there general way for this not write this condition ? i want general solution of this anyone help me for this ?

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Is it not sizing it properly, is it crashing...?

Comment: @ThomasMüller Problem is this new code not working in ipad and Iphone 4s its not scrolling becz of currentview's height

Comment: Can you `NSLog(@"view: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.bounds))` and `NSLog(@"sv: %@ %@", NSStringFromCGSize(scrMain.bounds), NSStringFromCGSize(scrMain.contentSize))` to see if the sizes are any different? If the scroll view's content size is the same as it's size it won't scroll.

Comment: @ThomasMüller not working for iphone4 and ipad this scrMain.bounds

Comment: It sounds like maybe `scrMain` is `nil`. What does `NSLog(@"%@", scrMain)` output?

Comment: @ThomasMüller output like 2014-12-09 10:23:42.647[7261:5353725] view: {768, 1024}
2014-12-09 10:23:42.648[7261:5353725] sv: {867, 1129} {0, 0}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66435/discussion-between-ios-and-thomas-muller). @ThomasMüller

Comment: Yeah, for some reason your contentSize is 0 x 0, so no scrolling...

Comment: Sorry, can't chat, I'm at work and that's blocked :-(

Comment: @ThomasMüller what i do for this ?

Comment: Can you add maybe the whole method with that code to your question?

Comment: I am stuck in this if else condition for ipad and iphone i am tried to sue this condition i want perfaction

Comment: @ThomasMüller http://pastie.org/9769196 here's my all code check this i dont want use if else condtion for this

Comment: Are you sure you need to calculate the contentSize height based on the bounds? If you have specific content that's in the scrollview, just calculate how much space you need and use that, independent of `self.view.bounds`. Also, check what the actual value is for `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` is. I wonder if it really is 480 for iPhone 4S. Could be 460 (480 minus status bar)?

Comment: i tried all the ways that i know but failed to do last option is use conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use following code

```
CGSize mainScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
 [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(mainScreenSize.width, mainScreenSize.height * 2.2)];
```

Also, set your UI layout for scrollview. (Or use resizing for scrollview). Make sure you execute the above lines of code after creating scrollview.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: are you using autolayout? please provide me more information.

Comment: pastie.org/9769196 this is my code ..no i am not using autolayout

Comment: Please make sure that you are not using auto layout. cause i have been messed with it before. Also, if you're using auto layout, you need to wait for the layout to be applied to the UIScrollView. This means you should set the Content Size in "viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Means i have to use autolayout for this ?

Comment: Noah. I mean to say that you can try setting contentsize on viewwillappear or in viewdidappear. Lets try please

Comment: [scrMain setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.scrMain.bounds.size.height *1.6)]; this working for all cases is it right ?